# SAP Table Display Area

Tags: user-interface, sap-gui

I've been having an issue with a table in one of the transactions where the table doesn't fit the maximized window. Is anyone aware of a solution to this problem?

[image: Example of display area problem]

Answer (score 0):

If it's a custom transaction, so custom screen, then it can be adjusted in the screen painter (extend the width of custom container and set it as automaticaly resizable in the attributes).